# Working with tags in Tkinter text widget using python

Tags: python, text, tags, tkinter

I'm trying color the text in the Tkinter text widget with help of tags in this way:

```
text = self.text_field.get(1.0, 'end') #text_field is a text widget
s = re.findall("\d+", text)
for i in s:
    self.text_field.tag_add(i, '1.0', 'end')
    self.text_field.tag_configure(i, background='yellow', 
                                  font='helvetica 14 bold', relief='raised')
```

The idea is that all tags are being dynamically created, because I get numbers from text widget and they can have any length. This code colors all text in the widget, but I need only numbers to be colored.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do

```
tag_add(i, '1.0', 'end')
```

You're making a tag that covers the whole text field. You need to just add the text on the numbers, using the `.start()` and `.stop()` methods of the regex match.

There's an example for doing syntax highlighting here:
http://forums.devshed.com/python-programming-11/syntax-highlighting-172406.html

Comment: Could/would you update your link to point directly at the example being referred to?

Comment: @martineau: sorry, it looks like that site's URL structure has changed, and I don't know how to get back to that post.

Comment: I think I found it. Since the code is short (and open source), I suggest you add it to your answer as well as link to it.

Answer (score 4):

There is an answer to a similar question that shows how to extend the text widget to have a method that highlights text based on a regular expression. For examples see [How to highlight text in a tkinter Text widget](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3781670/7432)