# Tkinter: How to get index for a specific word?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've resolved my previous issues.
Now, when my text is inserted it becomes bold from the word I need to the very END of the whole text. How do I highlight only the word?

```
self.text.insert('1.0', text)
self.text.grid()
tag_pos = self.text.search(word, '1.0')
self.text.tag_add('bold', tag_pos, END)
self.text.tag_configure('bold', font='TkDefaultFont 9 bold')
```

"self.text.tag_add('bold', tag_pos, END)" needs END to be the ending index of the word.

How do I retrieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
start = '1.0'
    while 1:                
        tag_start = self.text.search(word, start, stopindex=END, regexp=True)                
        if not tag_start: break
        tag_end = '%s+%dc' % (tag_start, len(word))
        self.text.tag_add('bold', tag_start, tag_end)
        self.text.tag_configure('bold', font='TkDefaultFont 9 bold')
        start = tag_start + "+1c"
```

Can somebody explain the '%s+%dc' and '+1c' notation?

Comment: Probably late, but I can explain the notation for you: Those percentage symbols are essentially things that you can place in strings, and the values will be substituted. if `tag_start = 5 and len(word) = 3`, then `tag_end` will equal to `"5+3c"`. If you've heard of the python `str.format()`, then it's similar to this, except try to always use the `str.format()` as it's cleaner, and easier to use :)

Answer (score 0):

"bold" is not the name of a valid font. You need to give it valid font description. tkinter comes with a `tkFont` module which lets you define fonts.

Comment: Bryan, in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781670/tkinter-text-highlighting-in-python) solution you're saying that .search should provide all the necessary information about the searched pattern, but it only returns the starting index of the word. How do I retrieve the ending index?