# How to highlight a word in text editor written with tkinter?

Tags: python, text, colors, tkinter, syntax-highlighting

I have written a simple text editor with `tkinter`. Now, I want to highlight some special words as the user is writing.

For instance, if the user wrote the word `define`, the word color would change to red.

Can I do that?

Comment: Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781670/tkinter-text-highlighting-in-python