# Priority of tags - Tkinter

Tags: tkinter, tags

I am currently working on a program which colours different categories in an expression in different colours. I am attaching some images, as it is difficult to explain it, using only words. 
I did have a look at [How to highlight text in a tkinter Text widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781670/how-to-highlight-text-in-a-tkinter-text-widget), but I don't find anything related to priority of tags.

**Image 1: Screenshot from a PDF, generated from latex code, using special style file**

[image]

As you can see, there is a green rectangle, containing a blue rectangle, which (blue rectangle) contains a red rectangle. 
When I try to recreate this using the program I have written - which is basically something like a text editor, I get the following ( in 2 steps):
**Image 2**

[image]

I add a blue tag to 'BLUE' and then a red tag to 'RED BLUE' - so far the priority of tags is working. But when I try to add a green tag to 'GREEN RED BLUE' I get the following:

**Image 3**

[image]

So the priority of tags messes up. Same happens if I try to do blue tag, wrapped by red tag, wrapped by blue tag:

**Image 4**

[image]

The functions I use to add tags are:

```
    def blueTerm(self,word):
    global blue
    global red
    global green
    self.txt.tag_add("blue", "sel.first", "sel.last")
    self.txt.tag_config('blue', background='deep sky blue', foreground='white')
    self.txt.tag_raise("red")
    self.txt.tag_raise("green")


def redSet(self,word):
    global blue
    global red
    global green
    self.txt.tag_add("red", "sel.first", "sel.last")
    self.txt.tag_config('red', background='red', foreground='black')
    self.txt.tag_raise("blue")
    self.txt.tag_raise("green")


def greenExp(self,word):
    self.txt.tag_add("green", "sel.first", "sel.last")
    self.txt.tag_config('green', background='green', foreground='black')
    self.txt.tag_raise("blue")
    self.txt.tag_raise("red")
```

My question is -  is there anything I can do with the 'priority' of tags so that I can get the same result as in Image 1?

NOTE: Even though my functions work and add tags, I get an error message:
*TclError: tag "red" isn't defined in text widget*.
Obviously these global variables green, red and blue don't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to highlight text in a tkinter Text widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781670/how-to-highlight-text-in-a-tkinter-text-widget)

Comment: @EricLevieil: I don't think so. This isn't asking how to highlight, it's asking about how to adjust the priority of tags. Related, but definitely not the same.

Comment: can you provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rather than just a snippet of code?

Comment: @BryanOakley : I believe OP asking about priority is an XY problem that comes from using `tag_add("green", "sel.first", "sel.last")` Whereas if he uses your highlight_text function, he won't have any problem.

Comment: @EricLevieil: I respectfully disagree. The user clearly knows how to highlight text -- the `highlight_text` function won't solve this problem because it doesn't address tag priority at all -- it simply calls `tag_add` exactly like the OP is already doing.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get the error that you get is because you are at some point trying to raise the "red" tag before ever having created the red tag. It has nothing to do with the global variable `red` (and `green` and `blue`, which all seem totally useless).

Because you get this error, the priorities are not getting set to what you think they are, and because of that, you get the visual appearance that you do.

Unless there's a reason for continually reconfiguring the tags each time you apply them, the simple solution is to configure them once, in the proper priority order, when you first create the text widget.

```
self.txt = tk.Text(...)
self.txt.tag_config('green', background='green', foreground='black')
self.txt.tag_config('red', background='red', foreground='black')
self.txt.tag_config('blue', background='deep sky blue', foreground='white')
```

Later, you merely need to add the tag to the text, without also having to configure the tag and juggle the priority:

```
def blueTerm(self,word):
    self.txt.tag_add("blue", "sel.first", "sel.last")

def redSet(self,word):
    self.txt.tag_add("red", "sel.first", "sel.last")

def greenExp(self,word):
    self.txt.tag_add("green", "sel.first", "sel.last")
```

Comment: I tried that, it only works in some cases - now I can do blue, wrapped in red, and the whole wrapped in green, But I can't do blue wrapped in red, wrapped in blue - at the end it all becomes blue. So there is a priority which is blue > red > green.

Comment: @onetramp: you can order the priority however you want. However, the priority is "global" -- if blue has higher priority than red for one word it's going to have the higher priority for everything in the widget. If you need different priorities for different sentences you'll need to use different tags.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, I will figure it out. Thanks a lot.