# How to set Margin or Offset tag?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am attempting to add a small automatic margin inside my text widget however I am having a hard time with writing the tags.

I have a text box and I am trying to insert text into that box while keeping a margin.

I can get the text that is inserted to have a margin but when I type past the last line the margin is gone. So far all I can dig up is how to write the tag and use it with `insert()` but I want to keep the margin always.

Question: Is there a way to keep the margin on all lines and not just the ones that were inserted from a file or string?

Note the same question extends to Offset tag because I experience the same problem with typing after the inserted text.

Here is what I have tried in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root, width = 10, height = 10)
text.pack()

text.tag_configure("marg", lmargin1 = 10, lmargin2 = 10)
text.insert("end", "Some random text!", ("marg"))

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Almost entirely for the question's sole value of presentation. This is how questions should be asked.

Comment: @Nae I do try to practice what I preach. If I am to ask everyone else to do a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then I should be doing my best to do this as well :)

Comment: Do you actually need the margin in the text, or do you just visually want a little whitespace so that the text isn't right next to the border? You could ignore the margin, and place the white text widget inside a white frame with some padding.

Comment: @BryanOakley Well I could probably do this however I was going to create a margin variable the user could change to increase or decrease the margin. I know that tkinter text box is not as powerful in the markup section as say word but I was attempting to improve on the visual/aesthetic.

Comment: You can also set it up so that you intercept the low level inserts and deletes to always include the margin tag.

Comment: @BryanOakley is that like binding a specific event to go to a costume function that has the margin tag? I think I can do this. I have worked with events in the past a little.

Comment: I've added a second answer to show how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the edge cases of adding and deleting text at the very start and end of the widget makes working with tags difficult.

If your goal is to maintain a margin, one solution is to create a proxy for the text widget so that you can intercept all inserts and deletes, and always add the margin each time the contents of the widget changes.

For example, start with a custom widget that generates a `<<TextModified>>` event whenever the widget is modified:

```
class CustomText(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # create a proxy for the underlying widget
        self._orig = self._w + "_orig"
        self.tk.call("rename", self._w, self._orig)
        self.tk.createcommand(self._w, self._proxy)

    def _proxy(self, command, *args):
        cmd = (self._orig, command) + args
        result = self.tk.call(cmd)

        if command in ("insert", "delete", "replace"):
            self.event_generate("<<TextModified>>")

        return result
```

(see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40618152/7432)

Next, modify your program to use this proxy to force the margin tag to always apply to the entire contents:

```
def add_margin(event):
    event.widget.tag_add("marg", "1.0", "end")

text = CustomText(root, width = 10, height = 6)
text.bind("<<TextModified>>", add_margin)
```

Comment: This works how I was hoping to get things to work. I will take a good look at this and try to use it also for my offset problem. Thanks for the great answers. I learn a lot from your post.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the tag to the entire range of text (including the final trailing newline), then new characters you type will inherit that tag.

Add the following, and perhaps it will work like you expect:

```
text.tag_add("marg", "1.0", "end")
```

Unfortunately, you'll lose this if you delete all of the text in the widget, but that can be worked around.

Comment: That looks to solve most of the problem. There is one issue thought. At the start of the inserted text if I select before the first letter and hit the return key then the top line loses its margin.

Comment: @Mike-SMT: yes, that unfortunately is the case.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and informative answer as always Bryan.