# How to change widget name in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I would like to change the name of a widget like this example :

```
window = Tk()
window.mainloop()
test_frame = Frame(window, name="test_frame")
test_frame.config(name="test_frame_name")
```

Do you have any solution to do something like this ?
I always get an error like `_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-name"`
Thanks for your help

Comment: What's are you trying to accomplish by changing the "name" of a widget? As the error message tells you, tkinter has no "name" option for widgets, so there's nothing tkinter itself would ever do with a "name".

Comment: As @ fhdrsdg said, there is no use for widget names in `tkinter`. If you really want to rename a widget, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40618152/11106801). There a text widget is renamed.

Answer (score 3):

Internally, the name is used as the unique identifier for the widget and cannot be changed once the widget has been created.