# why can i not use ctrl + v with a virtual event tkinter text widget python

Tags: python, tkinter, events, copy-paste

i use a tkinter text widget and i have copied [the script in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40617515/python-tkinter-text-modified-callback) to bind a event for every change the text widget.

the code for the text widget:

```py
"""I found this script here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40617515/python-tkinter-text-modified-callback"""
import tkinter as tk


class CustomText(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """A text widget that report on internal widget commands"""
        tk.Text.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # create a proxy for the underlying widget
        self._orig = self._w + "_orig"
        self.tk.call("rename", self._w, self._orig)
        self.tk.createcommand(self._w, self._proxy)

    def _proxy(self, command, *args):
        cmd = (self._orig, command) + args
        result = self.tk.call(cmd)

        if command in ("insert", "delete", "replace"):
            self.event_generate("<<TextModified>>")

        return result
```

now the problem is that when a paste some text in the text widget i get this error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\mylanguage\main.py", line 91, in <module>
    app.mainloop()
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1429, in mainloop
    self.tk.mainloop(n)
  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\mylanguage\customtext.py", line 17, in _proxy
    result = self.tk.call(cmd)
_tkinter.TclError: text doesn't contain any characters tagged with "sel"

Process finished with exit code 1
```

so i want i can paste some text without getting this error. can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_tkinter.TclError: text doesn't contain any characters tagged with "sel"
```

You are getting an error when you do either delete or copy. To solve problem. just add two tags one for **get** and one for **delete**.

Snippet code:

```
def _proxy(self, command, *args):
    # avoid error when copying
    if command == 'get' and (args[0] == 'sel.first' and args[1] == 'sel.last'): return

    # avoid error when deleting
    if command == 'delete' and (args[0] == 'sel.first' and args[1] == 'sel.last'): return

    cmd = (self._orig, command) + args
    result = self.tk.call(cmd)

    if command in ('insert', 'delete', 'replace'):
                self.event_generate('<<TextModified>>')

    return result
```

Screenshot before:

[image]

Screenshot after ctrl+v:

[image]

Comment: You're writing a lot of "try this code" answers. Please consider to add a brief summary to your changes, why they are needed and what you have changed. While we sometimes write example code on [so] where it's hard to explain everything about the code. A few lines of code won't be out of boundaries for a proper explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but it seems still somewhat ambiguous why this is needed. I mean, if I didn't knew the answer myself, I wouldn't get anything else then code from the answer. The mechanism of the tags you are referring to, why they are needed to be checked and how does it solve the problem? Keep in mind the purpose of this site is to be valuable for future visitors as well.