# Find a string in sentence and change the string's color and display in tkinter label python

Tags: python, tkinter, replace, colorama

I want to look for a selected keyword and change its font color in a label text.

The code below that print in terminal.

```
import colorama as color
text = 'This is a long strings. How many strings are there'
x = 'strings'

if x in text:
    print(text.replace(x,"{}{}{}".format(color.Fore.RED, x, color.Fore.RESET)))
root.mainloop()
```

The code works great in terminal. After that, i try to apply the print code into label

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
Label(root, text=text.replace(x,"{}{}{}".format(color.Fore.RED, x, color.Fore.RESET)))
```

The output after i applied become something like this in label:

> This is a long 口[31mstrings. How many 口[31mstrings are there

I have look around the solutions, and found that colorama only works on terminal. Is there any better way to change the string's font-color in GUI? Thank you !

Comment: You could try with [termcolor](https://pypi.org/project/termcolor/).

Comment: labels are not terminal windows. That's simply not how labels are designed to work.

Comment: You can change the color of portion of the text in a `Text` widget using tags but the way it works is completely different from when you color text in a terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution from this Link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3781773/8139776).

And i apply it into my code and it works like what it want.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
texts = 'This is a long strings. How many strings are there'
x = 'strings'

if x in texts:
    text = CustomText(root)   #This is a class that i use to look to highlight x string in texts
    text.insert(END, texts)
    text.tag_configure("red", foreground="#ff0000")
    text.highlight_pattern(x, "red")
    

text.grid(row = 0 ,column = 1)
root.mainloop()
```

And Here is the image:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIWur.png)

Thank you for @j_4321 and @Bryan Oakley.