# How to color words in tkinter text box but remove the color if the word is a substring of a string?

Tags: python, tkinter, text, tags

I am new to the whole 'tags' thing in a tkinter Text box I want to color certain words like the python IDLE does but by taking help from this example ==> [How to highlight text in a tkinter Text widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781670/tkinter-text-highlighting-in-python) I noticed that it highlights all the occurences of the entered string whereas what I want to do is to highlight the string only when it is a complete word, not when the string is a substring of a string. Example: I want to highlight occurences of 'or' in the below given text:

"We can go for the southern port or the northern port."

> We can go f***or*** the southern p***or***t ***or*** the n***or***thern p***or***t

There are five occurences of 'or' as bold-italics whereas it should have been only once.

There is one more thing, how to change color of text placed inside quotes ?
If you know answer to any of the above two parts of my question it would be really helpful

Please help me in solving this query...

Thanks in advance

Comment: have your tried using word boundaries (`\b`)? The regex should be `\bor\b`

Comment: @RamónMárquez: the text widget search uses [Tcl regularexpressions](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm), so `\b` won't work. Instead, Tcl uses `\m` and `\M` for word boundaries.

Comment: Even after searching I couldn't find usage of `\m`. Please I request give an example on how to do use that (with the above mentioned link's code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Details about Tcl regular expressions can be found [here](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M25). In particular,

> \y
> matches only at the beginning or end of a word

So using the pattern `r'\yor\y'` in `.highlight_pattern()` will only highlight the word "or" not the substrings.

Secondly, finding text between quotes can be done with the regular expression `r'"[^"]+"'`. `[^"]` means any character except quotes. If you do not want to highlight the quotes, then you need to add the tag from one character after the match start to one character before the match end. However, with this pattern, quoted text containing newlines will not be highlighted. If you also want to highlight quoted text containing newlines, you can use the regular expression `r'"([^"]|\n)+"'`.

Here is an example based on the answer from [How to highlight text in a tkinter Text widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781670/tkinter-text-highlighting-in-python)

```
import tkinter as tk

class CustomText(tk.Text):
    '''A text widget with a new method, highlight_pattern()

    example:

    text = CustomText()
    text.tag_configure("red", foreground="#ff0000")
    text.highlight_pattern("this should be red", "red")

    The highlight_pattern method is a simplified python
    version of the tcl code at http://wiki.tcl.tk/3246
    '''
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def highlight_pattern(self, pattern, tag, start="1.0", end="end",
                          regexp=False):
        '''Apply the given tag to all text that matches the given pattern

        If 'regexp' is set to True, pattern will be treated as a regular
        expression according to Tcl's regular expression syntax.
        '''
        self.tag_remove(tag, start, end) # remove tag first
        start = self.index(start)
        end = self.index(end)
        self.mark_set("matchStart", start)
        self.mark_set("matchEnd", start)
        self.mark_set("searchLimit", end)

        count = tk.IntVar()
        while True:
            index = self.search(pattern, "matchEnd", "searchLimit",
                                count=count, regexp=regexp)
            if index == "":
                break
            if count.get() == 0:
                break # degenerate pattern which matches zero-length strings
            self.mark_set("matchStart", index)
            self.mark_set("matchEnd", "%s+%sc" % (index, count.get()))
            self.tag_add(tag, "matchStart", "matchEnd")

    def highlight_quoted_text(self, tag, start="1.0", end="end"):
        self.tag_remove(tag, start, end) # remove tag first
        start = self.index(start)
        end = self.index(end)

        count = tk.IntVar()
        while True:
            index = self.search(r'"[^"]+"', start, end,
                                count=count, regexp=True)
            if index == "":
                break

            start = self.index("%s+%sc" % (index, count.get()))
            self.tag_add(tag, "%s+1c" % index, "%s-1c" % start)


root = tk.Tk()
text = CustomText(root)
text.tag_configure('highlight', background='yellow')
text.tag_configure('quoted', background='orange')
text.pack()


text.insert('1.0', "We can go for the southern port or the northern port.\n\"Text surronded by quotes\" and regular text without quotes and \"quoted text again\"")
tk.Button(root, text='Highlight "or"', command=lambda: text.highlight_pattern(r'\yor\y', 'highlight', regexp=True)).pack()
tk.Button(root, text='Highlight quoted', command=lambda: text.highlight_quoted_text('quoted')).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Great man!! @j_4321, it worked nicely but can you explain how to make multiline string ?
The only problem with `r'"([^"]|\n)+"'` is that first you have to type everything in the same line and then if you press Return the color won't change but if after pressing Return I type anything inside the quotes it doesn't change the color

Comment: For example if first I type "Yo this is a multiline string" and then I separate it out:
"Yo\n

 this is a \n

multiline \n

string"

it doesn't create any color difference but if I type anything in between 
"Yo\n

 this is a \n

ulti-multi-penalty line\n

string"

It doesn't highlight the newly entered words

Comment: These comments don't allow multiline I guess so I have used `\n` instead

Comment: Any idea on how to remove tags if the highlighted word's strings are being deleted ??

Comment: @prerakl123 For the last comment, you can remove the tag before searching for the word/quoted text with `.tag_remove(tag, start, end)`. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @prerakl123 For the comments about newlines, sorry but I don't understand what is the problem.

Comment: the problem is that if I typed a sentence in multiline string quotes and in between the string I press Return say in between this sentence """The quick brown <HERE> fox danced""" then the color of 1st line -> 'The quick brown' and 2nd line -> 'fox danced' remains whatever I assigned them (which is good) but now after the line break if I add anything say a word 'long' at the end of first line then the sentence becomes "The quick brown long" but the newly added word does not get highlighted. This is the problem I am trying to explain above.

Comment: @prerakl123 I cannot reproduce the issue: I type your sentence, click on the "Highlight quoted" button, this highlights the sentence. Then I add the newline (I get the same result if I add the newline before clicking since I used the regexp `r'"([^"]|\n)+"'`) and type another word and everything stays highlighted.

Comment: Oh many thanks for looking into the issue @j_4321 but I resolved it because I wasn't using buttons for doing the work, I was using a self calling function and I missed a parameter which I looked into and it worked.