# How to create logic to set color for certain word like python shell in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, types, import, colors

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3kgc.jpg)

How to create logic to set color for certain word like python shell in python tkinter
for example if I type "import" is color should be blue and other stay remains same as given on image in the link above

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place to ask for code from scratch. You need to try it yourself and post the problem you came across.

Comment: It is the same question as your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71297292/how-to-set-a-custom-color-for-certain-word-like-ide-in-python-tkinter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE**: The code below is based on the following declarations -:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry('400x300')
root.title('Widget(With Colored Keywords)')

text = tk.Text(root, background = '#1f1f14', foreground = 'white', insertbackground = 'white')
text.pack()
```

---

The behavior required can be achieved using tags in tkinter `Text` widget, you can find the position of the word using regex(`pos` and `last_pos`), and then define a tag based on the position.

We can add a tag to the text widget if we know the start and end position of the tag using `tag_add` method of the Text widget.

```
tkinter.Text.tag_add(tagname, start_pos, end_pos)
```

Note that the position arguments to passed must be in [Text widget index](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/text-index.html) format.

Further, we use `tag_config` method of the text widget to configure properties of the tag, in this case the `foreground`.

This tag can be then used to modify the `foreground` color property of the part of the text that is within that tag.

```
def check_for_keywords(keyword_dict) :
    for i in keyword_dict :
        text.tag_remove(i, '1.0', tk.END)
        
        pos = 1.0
        while 1:
            pattern = r'\m{}\M'.format(i)
            pos = text.search(pattern, pos, regexp = True, stopindex = tk.END)
            if not pos:
                break
            last_pos = '%s+%dc' % (pos, len(i))
            text.tag_add(i, pos, last_pos)
            pos = last_pos
        text.tag_config(i, foreground = keyword_dict[i])
    root.after(1000, check_for_keywords)
    return
```

Given a dictionary, with {keyword : color_name} mapping, a function can be made to check for keywords. Also note that this function will have to be called using the after method of the tkinter window every second(you can change the check timings based on the suitability of it with your project).

```
keyword_dict = {'label' : 'red', 'button' : 'blue', 'gml' : 'orange'}

root.after(1000, lambda : check_for_keywords(keyword_dict)) #Checks every one second.
root.mainloop()
```

The full code will become -:

```
import tkinter as tk

def check_for_keywords(keyword_dict) :
    
    for i in keyword_dict :
        text.tag_remove(i, '1.0', tk.END)
        
        pos = 1.0
        while 1:
            pattern = r'\m{}\M'.format(i)
            pos = text.search(pattern, pos, regexp = True, stopindex = tk.END)
            if not pos:
                break
            last_pos = '%s+%dc' % (pos, len(i))
            text.tag_add(i, pos, last_pos)
            pos = last_pos
        text.tag_config(i, foreground = keyword_dict[i])
    root.after(1000, lambda : check_for_keywords(keyword_dict))
    return

keyword_dict = {'label' : 'red', 'button' : 'blue', 'gml' : 'orange'} #GML CODING KEYWORDS TEST DICT

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry('400x300')
root.title('Widget(With Colored Keywords)')

text = tk.Text(root, background = '#1f1f14', foreground = 'white', insertbackground = 'white')
text.pack()

root.after(1000, lambda : check_for_keywords(keyword_dict)) #Checks every one second.
root.mainloop()
```

Now, on typing any of the mentioned keywords, the keywords are highlighted -:
[image: OUTPUT]

---

**NOTE:**
Also more helpful information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781670/how-to-highlight-text-in-a-tkinter-text-widget).

For more information on how to deal with tags, [this](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html#tags) might also be a useful resource.

Comment: sir can i put many keys to same value

Comment: @Anmol yes you can :)

Comment: @Anmol what error does it show?

Comment: @Anmol uhh ok..

Comment: when putting symbols like *,#,etc```` tkinter.TclError: couldn't compile regular expression pattern: quantifier operand invalid```

Comment: what line is this error occurring on?

Comment: If you want to use symbols, a few changes have to be done in the code, you can ask a separate question for that, i cannot add it into this question as it is just about highlighting words.

Comment: sir I post anothter question for symbols so please can you tell me there how to set custom colors for symbols

Comment: question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71309952/how-to-set-custom-color-for-symbols-like-etc-in-python-tkinter

Comment: @Anmol, only the regex expression being used to check for words has to be switched to a suitable one for symbols, rest of the code remains the same.