# How to set custom color for symbols like*,#,etc in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, set, symbols

How to set specific color for certain symbols like *,#,etc '
example if I type "*" it's color should be blue and other stay remain same.

typedecker sir i am binding you function like this but this is not working

```
from tkinter import*
root = Tk()
def check_for_symbols(symbol_dict) :
    for i in symbol_dict :
        text.tag_remove(i, '1.0', END)
        
        pos = 1.0
        while 1:
            pos = text.search(i, pos, regexp = True, stopindex = END)
            if not pos:
                break
            last_pos = '%s+%dc' % (pos, len(i)) # The only change
            text.tag_add(i, pos, last_pos)
            pos = last_pos
        text.tag_config(i, foreground = symbol_dict[i])
    root.after(1000, lambda:check_for_symbols(symbol_dict))
    return
symbol_dict = {
    "*":"blue"
}
text = Text(root, background = "gray19", foreground = "white", insertbackground = 'white',font="Consolas 15 italic")
text.pack(expand=True,fill=BOTH)
root.after(1000, lambda : check_for_symbols(symbol_dict))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: In a label? entry widget? canvas? text widget? Everywhere? Have you done any research about setting the color of individual characters? Why do you need our help?

Comment: in text widgets but only symbols because i already made a function to set custom color for characters but it is not appliccable on symbols

Comment: example when I type "*" it should be in blue color and other stays remains same

Comment: If you can do it for characters then why can't you do it for symbols? They are all just characters in a character set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same procedure as followed in the case of words [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71305716/how-to-create-logic-to-set-color-for-certain-word-like-python-shell-in-python-tk/71306010#71306010) by me, can be followed, the only change will be in the regex expression that is to be used to detect the symbols.

```
last_pos = '%s+%dc' % (pos, len(i)) # The only change
```

The full `check_for_symbols` function with the necessary changes in place will look like -:

```
def check_for_symbols(symbol_dict) : # pass symbol dict as argument using lambda construct.
#    symbol dict format-: {keyword : color}
    
    for i in symbol_dict :
        text.tag_remove(i, '1.0', tk.END)
        
        pos = 1.0
        while 1:
            pos = text.search(i, pos, regexp = True, stopindex = tk.END)
            if not pos:
                break
            last_pos = '%s+%dc' % (pos, len(i)) # The only change
            text.tag_add(i, pos, last_pos)
            pos = last_pos
        text.tag_config(i, foreground = symbol_dict[i])
    root.after(1000, check_for_symbols)
    return
```

Comment: sir I am unable to bind this function to my text widgets ,I tried so many times

Comment: @Anmol use lambda construct and pass a symbol dictionary(make a separate one similar to the one for keywords..) with the format specified and pass it as an argument.

Comment: sir it still shows this  error     """"return str(self.tk.call(tuple(args)))
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't compile regular expression pattern: quantifier operand invalid"""

Comment: sir post my code above show how i am binding your function sir please check whats wrong

Comment: it still shows error sir