# how to highlight text in a tkinter text widget between two specific characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I didn't find anything exact on this topic, there were some things but they didn't cover how to highlight text in a tkinter text widget between two specific characters.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
win=Tk()
win.title("window")
win.geometry('500x500')
textwidget=Text(font=('Consolas',12),background='black',foreground='white')
textwidget.pack(expand=True,fill=BOTH)
textwidget.tag_config('litred', foreground='red')
textwidget.tag_config('string', foreground='yellow')
textwidget.tag_config('command', foreground='red')
list_of_words = ['I','you','me']
def lit():
    textwidget.tag_remove('command', '1.0', END)
    textwidget.tag_remove('string', '1.0', END)
    #others
    for word in list_of_words:
        idx = '1.0'
        while idx:
            idx = textwidget.search(word, idx, nocase=1, stopindex=END)
            if idx:
                lastidx = '%s+%dc' % (idx, len(word))
                textwidget.tag_add('command', idx, lastidx)
                idx = lastidx
    #strings
    idx = '1.0'
    idx2=1
    while idx:
        idx = textwidget.search("\"", idx, nocase=1, stopindex=END)
        if idx:
            idx2 = textwidget.search(word, idx, nocase=1, stopindex=END)
            if idx2:
                textwidget.tag_add('string', idx, idx2)
                idx = idx2[0:2]+str(int(idx2[2])+1)
            else:
                textwidget.tag_add('string', idx, END)
                idx2=0
                idx=0
while True:
    lit()
    win.update()
```

the code works but instead of highlighting between the two '"' it highlights everywhere

I am trying to make a text editor which highlights specific words and stuff... you get the point.
and I don't know why my code doesn't work accordingly; I might have made mistakes that nobody makes (I'm not an expert) and it might be something else.
If you can please tell me why it doesn't work or how I should do it so that it works.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues on searching for strings:

- *wrong pattern (`word`) and index (`idx`)* when searching for closing double-quote
- wrong start index (`idx = idx2[0:2]+str(int(idx2[2])+1)`) when searching next pair of double-quotes

Below is the modified code for searching strings:

```py
#strings
idx = '1.0'
while idx:
    idx = textwidget.search('"', idx, nocase=1, stopindex=END)
    if idx:
        # should not use word for the pattern
        # starting index should be one character after idx
        idx2 = textwidget.search('"', f'{idx}+1c', nocase=1, stopindex=END)
        if idx2:
            idx2 = f"{idx2}+1c"
            textwidget.tag_add('string', idx, idx2)
            # set next starting index
            idx = idx2
        else:
            textwidget.tag_add('string', idx, END)
            idx2 = 0
            idx = 0
```

Note that it still does not work properly when there is something like `"\""` or `'"'` in the text.

Result:

[image]

Comment: If you want a pre-made solution for searching a text widget and highlighting results, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781670/how-to-highlight-text-in-a-tkinter-text-widget/3781773#3781773

Comment: @BryanOakley I just point out what is wrong on OP code on searching *quoted strings*, I am not the one want to create syntax highlighting feature.  Also your linked solution is on highlighting *keywords*, not on highlighting quoted strings.

Comment: the solution I linked to can search for any string pattern as it supports regular expressions, including quoted strings.