# Handle multiple tags in a Text widget when each tag adds a style to the text?

Tags: python, text, fonts, tags, tkinter

I want to create a toolbar for a text widget that allows you to select bold or italic text, as well as their combination (bold and italic together).

I've been looking at this response to [Advanced Tkinter text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732605/advanced-tkinter-text-box), as well as code for the [StyledText](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/StyledText) widget, but neither answers my question.

The basic way to configure tags:

```
txtWidget.tag_configure("bold", font=my_bold_font)
txtWidget.tag_configure("italic", font=my_italic_font)
```

It means you can associate a single font with a single tag, but there doesn't appear to be any way (on the surface) to associate tag combinations with a font.

Is the best way to proceed to create a tag_bind event to a method that will figure out my tag combinations and assign the font accordingly, or is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, this is one of the few weaknesses of the text widget. If you want both bold and italic you need a tag with a font that has both of those attributes. You can create new tags on the fly so it's not an impossible problem to solve, but it can be a bit tedious to figure out which characters in a range need the "bold" tag, which need the "italic" tag, and which needs a new "bold_italic" tag.

Comment: Do you have an implemented solution perchance?

Comment: @Xenomorph: no. I've done it, but I don't know where the code is. I probably did it in Tcl rather than Python.