# Set to bold the selected text using tags

Tags: python, text, tkinter

I have been working trying to make a simple text editor, and have been experimenting with tags. I have been able to create justifying using tags. Now I'm adding a bold option.

My problem is that I can't find many examples of using the `"sel"` tag, a tag used on current selection.

Whenever I use the `SEL` tag, the text is only bold as long as it is highlighted, when it becomes un-highlighted, it reverts back to its old skinny font.

This is a small portion of my code:

```
def Bold(self, body, Just, Line, selected font):
    bold font = tkFont.Font(family=selectedfont, weight="bold")
    selected font = boldfont
    body.tag_config("sel",font=selectedfont)
    body.tag_add("sel", 1.0,END)
```

When the `Bold` button is pressed, the previous function is called.
Right now, I have the `body.tag_add("sel", 1.0, END)` set from `1.0` to `END`, because I don't know how to get the selected domain.
I've tried `<<Selection>>`, but after experimenting for a long time, it hasn't helped me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would only need `tag_add()` inside of your function:

```
import Tkinter as tk

def make_bold():
    aText.tag_add("bt", "sel.first", "sel.last")

lord = tk.Tk()

aText = tk.Text(lord, font=("Georgia", "12"))
aText.grid()

aButton = tk.Button(lord, text="bold", command=make_bold)
aButton.grid()

aText.tag_config("bt", font=("Georgia", "12", "bold"))

lord.mainloop()
```

I just happened across a rather educational [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3736494/1217270) by none other than Bryan Oakley,
on a completely unrelated search!

Here is a quick example of the more dynamic alternative:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont

def make_bold():
    current_tags = aText.tag_names("sel.first")
    if "bt" in current_tags:
        aText.tag_remove("bt", "sel.first", "sel.last")
    else:
        aText.tag_add("bt", "sel.first", "sel.last")


lord = tk.Tk()

aText = tk.Text(lord, font=("Georgia", "12"))
aText.grid()

aButton = tk.Button(lord, text="bold", command=make_bold)
aButton.grid()

bold_font = tkFont.Font(aText, aText.cget("font"))
bold_font.configure(weight="bold")
aText.tag_configure("bt", font=bold_font)

lord.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand. So the SEl only applies to text that is highlighted constantly. If you highlight it goes away. But you can use that specific tag to get the domain and apply another tag that includes bold font.
Thank you, this has helped me with this and many other things I have planned to do in the future such as colored text.

Comment: @reallycoolnerd I just updated my answer. You might find it useful.

Comment: it took me a little while to understand it, but I have picked this apart and am able to interpret it....thank you, it helped me a bunch for the Bold toggle

Answer (score 2):

Tag attributes belong to the tag, not to the text. So, when you highlight something then apply attributes to the `"sel"` tag, it only affects text that has the `"sel"` tag. When you remove the tag (by unhighlighting), the attributes revert to the default (or to any other tags that might be present).

To make text bold, you must create a tag that has the bold attribute and assign that tag to the text. As long as the text has that tag, it will have the attributes of that tag.

Comment: So i need to get the start position of the highlighting and the end position of the highlighting, and use that as the domain in my bold tag?

Comment: Never mind, i played around with the above answer and I forgot to change my domain on one of the tags. thank you though this has also helped me understand tags much better

Comment: @reallycoolnerd: what do you mean when you syb"domain"? Tkinter has nothing named a "domain" in the text widget or any other widget.

Comment: By domain, I refer to the 1.0, END in the ....sorry its a term from Calculus that I like to use. I mean it by the area the .tag is applied to. So from ("sel",1.1,1.3) 1.1 to 1.3 is my domain. I know its not what it is defined as in the tag, i just used it as a general term. Sorry about that