# Create a hyperlink in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to create a hyperlink in Tkinter. Here is my approach:

```
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser

def callback(event):
    webbrowser.open_new(r"http://www.google.com")

root = Tk()
link = Label(root, text="Google Hyperlink", fg="blue", cursor="hand2")
link.pack()
link.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
root.mainloop()
```

I have a piece of text, a few sentences, and only a few words in it should be a hyperlink. How can I do that? I need a simple solution.

Comment: What does "I have a text" mean? Do you mean you are using a `Text` widget?

Comment: @BryanOakley, no, I mean text.

Comment: You can't do what you want with a label. You'll have to either use a `Text` widget, a `Canvas` widget, or a custom widget made up of multiple `Label` widgets. The `Label` widget doesn't support creating links inside portions of the text.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Text` (or `Canvas`) widget. You can make them look like label, so that users won;t tell the difference.

Create a tag within your `Text` (see example here [Set to bold the selected text using tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900906/set-to-bold-the-selected-text-using-tags)) and bind the tag to the callback.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by others, using a `Text` widget is the best way to do this.

One potential solution to this problem is provided [here](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-text-hyperlink.htm)