# How to get the index of word being searched in tkinter text box

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a UI using tkinter. I have a text box in which the user can write multiple lines. I need to search those lines for certain words and highlight them.

Currently, when I search for a word and try to color it using `tag_configure` and `tag_add`, I get an error, "bad index".

What I've learned after reading certain pages on internet is that the start and end indices used in `tag_add` are those of the format `row.column` (please correct me if I am going wrong somewhere).

Can anyone help me in getting the index in this format from the tkinter UI directly for highlighting? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why not show us original error message? And your code?

Comment: see [Explain Tkinter text search method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19466754/1832058)

Answer (score 8):

It has to be float number - for example first char in text is `1.0`  (not string `"1.0"`)

---

**EDIT:** I made mistake. It can be string - and it have to be string because `1.1` and `1.10` is the same float number (as said [Bryan Oakley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley)) - but I leave this working example.

---

```
from Tkinter import *

#------------------------------------

root = Tk()

#---

t = Text(root)
t.pack()

t.insert(0.0, 'Hello World of Tkinter. And World of Python.')

# create tag style
t.tag_config("red_tag", foreground="red", underline=1)

#---

word = 'World'

# word length use as offset to get end position for tag
offset = '+%dc' % len(word) # +5c (5 chars)

# search word from first char (1.0) to the end of text (END)
pos_start = t.search(word, '1.0', END)

# check if found the word
while pos_start:

    # create end position by adding (as string "+5c") number of chars in searched word 
    pos_end = pos_start + offset

    print pos_start, pos_end # 1.6 1.6+5c :for first `World`

    # add tag
    t.tag_add('red_tag', pos_start, pos_end)

    # search again from pos_end to the end of text (END)
    pos_start = t.search(word, pos_end, END)

#---

root.mainloop()

#------------------------------------
```

[image]

Comment: Your statement "it has to be a float number" is incorrect. It's not a floating point number, it's a string of the form "line.character". It may look like a floating pointnumber, but it's not. For example, the floating point numbers 1.1 and 1.10 represent the same number but they do _not_ represent the same character in a text widget.

Comment: You right - now I see my mistake `1.1 and 1.10` - I always used float but only `1.0` to clear all text.

Comment: thanks all..
i was able to do it with the help of this post..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732605/advanced-tkinter-text-box