# Text box with squiggly lines

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, cross-platform

I need to develop cross platform spell checker for Sinhala language with word suggestions. For that I need a UI framework which supports squiggly lines under words and right click base context menus for words. Ideally something like the picture below.

[image]

My initial idea was to use Tkinter and Python. But I could not find anyway to accomplish this task.Is there anyway I can accomplish this task with Tkinter? Or is there any cross platform GUI framework which supports this kind of task? Or is there a way for me to write this feature from scratch?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732605/add-advanced-features-to-a-tkinter-text-widget

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter doesn't support squiggly lines, and trying to simulate them or write them from scratch would be a considerable amount of work. You can, however, underline words and change other visual attributes such as the font, foreground and background colors.

Tkinter also supports right-click menus.