# tkinter - managing multiple tags

Tags: python, text, tkinter, tags

So, the the tkinter text editor!
The editor obviously needs to have text styles, which need to change typed text to whatever formatting is currently selected, using tags. But the problem is that the tag name needs to change when the formatting changes, otherwise the tag would be applied to the whole text.
(This was a problem that I was struggling to identify for quite some time)
To avoid this, you would need a LOT of tags (like `bold, both, calibri` etc), so the code would look like this

```
if style == 'bold':
    tag_add('bold', 'insert -1c', 'insert')
    tag_configure('bold', font=('Calibri', 12, 'bold'))

if stlye == 'italic':
    etc etc
```

This is awful code, and makes different fonts/sizes impossible.
Is there a correct way of organising multiple tags like this, something like

```
tag.add(currentstyle, 'insert -1c', 'insert')
tag.config(currentstyle, font=(currentfont, currentsize, currentweight, currentslant))
```

Thanks for your help

**UPDATE**
solved with no small amount of help from Bryan

```
tagname = '{}-{}-{}-{}'.format(font, fontsize, weight, slant)

textbox.tag_add(tagname, 'insert -1c', 'insert')
textbox.tag_configure(tagname, font=(font, fontsize, weight, slant))
```

now every tag has a unique name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to create a unique tag for every different font you use. In practice this isn't so bad, because most documents only use 3-4 variations, or perhaps a worst case of maybe a dozen. The only real difficulty is that if you want both bold and italics you have to create a bold tag, an italics tag, and a bold-italics tag.

> This is awful code, and makes different fonts/sizes impossible.

It doesn't make it impossible, just slightly difficult. Your code is actually pretty close to how you would do it.

When a user changes the style of a character, you need to create a canonical form for the style name by combining the current style and any new attributes. For example, if the character is currently bold 12 point and they change it to italic 14 point, the new tag might be "italic-12".  If they want to keep the bold it might be "bold-italic-12". You then need to check for whether you have a tag by that name, and create it if you don't, then remove any previous font tag and add the new font tag.

This is really only a problem with fonts. For other attributes such as colors and borders you can simply use all the different tags separately (ie: if you create a tag for "background-blue" and "foreground-red", you can apply both of those tags separately to the text.

I provide an example that does something similar to this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3736494/7432

Comment: Guess you have to think outside of the box sometimes, thanks!

Comment: @EriktheRed: tkinter is more like a lumber store than a furniture store. You can create really nice interfaces with Tkinter, but you sometimes have to do the work yourself.